# pandas - merge multiple dataframe column name

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to merge multiple dataframe. I got below example work but the column name a little bit confuse:

```
import pandas as pd

def mergedf(dfs, countfiles,oncolumn,i=0):
    if i == (countfiles - 1): # it gets to the second to last and merges it with the last
        return dfs[i]

    dfm = dfs[i].merge(mergedf(dfs, countfiles,oncolumn,i=i+1), on=oncolumn)
    return dfm

df1 = pd.DataFrame([["x", 1],["y", 2]], columns=["A", "B"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["x", 3],["y", 4]], columns=["A", "B"])
df3 = pd.DataFrame([["x", 5],["y", 6]], columns=["A", "B"])
df4 = pd.DataFrame([["x", 7],["y", 8]], columns=["A", "B"])
df5 = pd.DataFrame([["x", 9],["y", 10]], columns=["A", "B"])

print(df1)

dfs = [df1,df2,df3,df4,df5]
df = mergedf(dfs, len(dfs),'A')

print(df)
```

Current output:

```
   A  B
0  x  1
1  y  2

   A  B  B_x  B_y  B_x  B_y
0  x  1    3    5    7    9
1  y  2    4    6    8   10
```

The colum name is (A,B,B_x,B_y,B_x,B_y),some column name is repeated. I would like the result column name as (A,B0,B1,B2,B3,B4),just as below:

```
   A  B0  B1   B2   B3   B4
0  x  1    3    5    7    9
1  y  2    4    6    8   10
```

Comment: Why not change the column names before merging?

Comment: For abstraction purpose maybe..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
def mergedf(dfs, countfiles,oncolumn): # don't need i=0 for this
    dfsi = [df.set_index(oncolumn) for df in dfs]
    df_out = pd.concat(dfsi, keys=range(countfiles), axis=1)
    df_out.columns = [f'{b}{a}' for a, b in df_out.columns]
    return df_out

df = mergedf(dfs,  len(dfs), 'A').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   A  B0  B1  B2  B3  B4
0  x   1   3   5   7   9
1  y   2   4   6   8  10
```

Here, we are using the `keys` parameter of `pd.concat` to create the incremented number of times for B.  `pd.concat` as most pandas methods, will align dataframes along the index, called *intrinsic data alignment*, hence we are moving the 'joining' column into the index and `reset_index` afterwards.

---

Option 2: You can rename and use join:

```
dfsi = [df.rename(columns={'B':f'B{i}'}).set_index('A') for i, df in enumerate(dfs)]
df_out = dfsi[0].join(dfsi[1:]).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   A  B0  B1  B2  B3  B4
0  x   1   3   5   7   9
1  y   2   4   6   8  10
```